# laravel 5.4 belongsTo and hasMany does't work with 2 foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, blueprint

I tried to get comments with one post and I am using the relationship hasMany && belongsTo. I used table posts and comments.

This is the tow model

post model :

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
  public function user(){

    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
  }
  /**
   * Get the comments for the blog post.
   */
  public function comments()
  {
     return $this->hasMany('App\Comment' );
  }
}
```

and comment model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Comment extends Model
{

    /**
     * Get the post that owns the comment.
     */
    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
    }
}
```

and comment table contain 2 foreign keys
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5gL0.png)

When I need to select 1 post and all comments the server returns only post

```
$Post = Post::find( $id ) ;
```

Comment: Your code is about posts and comments, then you ask about finding a  Question.

Comment: check mor time please i update

Comment: Post will return one post, but you can access the comments by using `$Post->comments`

Comment: `$Post->comments` i used this but retutrn null

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$Post = Post::find( $id )->with('comment') ;
```